# Microsoft Teams adds extra new lines if a JSON is sent as message

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams is adding extra new lines if a JSON is sent as message.

When a JSON is sent as message to someone in Microsoft Teams, It adds extra newline after each line.

When the other person wants to copy and use the JSON in the REST API, the APIs throw JSON parsing error.

For a workaround, to send the JSON we save the JSON in a file and send the file.

Is someone aware of the resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. We have raised a bug for this. Meanwhile you could use the formatting features in chat window and send JSON as a code snippet to avoid this issue.
[image]

[image]